# Loading XML with possible infinite tags

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, infinite-loop

(I'm doing this in AS3, but I'm sure the answer could be given in psuedocode)

Basically, I have a XML file similar to:

```
<Main>
 <Event>
  <Name>Blah</Name>
  <Event>
   <Name>Blah2</Name>
   <Event>
    <Name>Blah3</Name>
    ...
   </Event>
  </Event>
 </Event>
</Main>
```

Yeah, to some extent it's poor design. But the idea I'm going for is that any Event has the potential to compromise of other Events and this idea kinda loops.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: can you please explain a little more clearly?

Comment: how is it infinite? the xml is finite by definition. It is a file on the disk.

Comment: In the sense that there is no set number of nested <Event> tags.
That's what I mean by 'infinite'

Comment: Nothing wrong with "infinite" nested elements. That's how you do a tree, for instance.

Comment: How to do do what? OK you have an XML file with an unknown amount of event tags nested. Ok, so what do you want to do with them? Like you want to get all the names? then you can with something like Main..Name

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion ?

Comment: I get that part, but how...? Like a recursive function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml:XML = <Main>
                <Event>
                  <Name>Name1<Name>
                  <Event>
                     <Name>Name2</Name>
                     ...........
                  </Event>
                </Event>

              </Main>
var event:MyEvent = getEvent(xml);

function getEvent(xml:XML):MyEvent
{

    var event:MyEvent = new MyEvent();
     var xmlList:XMLList = xml.children();
     for(i = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++){
     if(xml[i].hasOwnProperty("Name")){
       event.name = xml[i]["Name"];
      }
     if(xml[i].hasOwnProperty("Event")){
       event.event = getEventVO(xml[i]["Event"]);
      }

     }
    return event;

}
```

MyEvent.as

```
package
{

   public class MyEvent
   {

     public var name:String;
     public var event:Event;

     public function MyEvent():void
     {
     }
   }

}
```